# Probability of getting $1$ out of $3$ shots

Tags: probability

The question is:

> > Probability of scoring $1$ out of $3$ shots when you have 80% throw rate.

I solved this problem in the inverse way:

P(At least one basket) = $1$ - P(No basket) = $1$ - ($.20 \times .20 \times .20) = 0.992 ~ or ~99.2 \% $

I wanted to know how would I go about solving this the other (which I realize is not the best way)..

Comment: Which do you mean, "at least one" or "exactly one"?

Comment: If I had to put some money on the exact meaning of *Probability of scoring 1 out of 3 shots*, I would bet on *exactly one hit*. Then the numerical answer is 9.6%.

Comment: I agree that this is confusing, but technically, if you score twice, you have scored once. Also, the questioner supports this via his/her calculations. She also mentions P(At least one basket), which isn't very ambiguous.

Comment: @C.Williamson: The text is **1 out of 3**, the rest is an interpretation by the OP.

Comment: @RobertIsrael its actually atleast

Answer (score 1):

The way you do this is $3\choose{1}$(.8*.2*.2)+$3\choose{2}$(.8*.8*.2)+$3\choose{3}$$(.8^3)$
This equals 0.992.
There are $3\choose{1}$ ways to get one shot, $3\choose{2}$ ways to get two and $3\choose{3}$ ways to get all of them. Note that I could have just as easily counted misses rather than successful shots, which is okay, since binomial coefficients satisfy $n\choose{k}$=$n\choose{n-k}$.

Answer (score 1):

A way which nobody has mentioned is this:

The probability is: getting the first throw + missing the first throw but getting the second + missing the first 2 but getting the third.

0.8+0.2*0.8+0.2*0.2*0.8=0.8+0.16+0.032=0.992

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ***independence*** between the results of every two shots, then the scoring variable $K$ out of $n$ shots with success rate of $p$ is (we write [$K$~$B(n,p)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Specification))

$$ Pr(K=k)=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} $$

($K=2$ means two shots of success, and $Pr()$ means probability.)

So in your case:
$$\begin{align}
    Pr(K>0)&=Pr(K=3)+Pr(K=2)+Pr(K=1)          \\
    &={3\choose 3}0.8^3 + {3\choose 2}0.8^2 0.2^1 + {3\choose 1}0.8^1 0.2^2 \\
    &=0.512+0.384+0.096 \\
    &=0.992             \\
    &=1-Pr(K=0)
  \end{align}$$

So, actually $1-Pr(K=0)$ would be the best way to go for -- easy calculation.